# Global dimension of graded Lie algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

The *rational global dimension* of a graded algebra $A=(A_k)_{k\geq 0}$, with $A_0=\mathbb Q$, denoted here ${\rm gl}\dim A$ is defined to be the greatest integer $k$ (or $\infty$) such that ${\rm Ext}^k_{A}(\mathbb Q,-)\neq 0$.

I'm interested on the case when $A=L$ is a graded Lie algebra to compare $\frac{\ln (\dim L)}{{\rm gl}\dim L}$ and $\ln 2$.

Any comments or references are welcome. Thank you

Comment: Dear MyIsmail, you should add more tags. Even though your problem comes from a topological question it is indeed an algebraic problem. Best

Comment: @OliverStraser: Thanks for the suggestion. It is done

Comment: There are two definitions of graded Lie algebra (with grading in nonnegative integers), one being a Lie algebra with a multiplicative grading, and one being a non-associative algebra law and a multiplicative grading, and a "graded-Lie" condition. I'm not sure the OP and the answer agree on the definition, and I'm not sure at all what the OP has in mind, so this should be clarified. (It's quite dire to use such ambiguous terminologies but this is what some people do; the term Lie superalgebra for the second meaning is much better.)

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but here are some examples which might be informative:

First consider a finite-dimensional Lie algebra $L$ over an arbitrary field $k$. Assume that $L$ is concentrated in purely even degrees. Set $d = dim(L)$. Let $U(L)$ be the universal enveloping algebra of $L$. Then there is a standard (finite!) $U(L)$-free resolution of the trivial module $k$,

$$P_\bullet: U(L) \otimes \Lambda^d(L) \rightarrow U(L) \otimes \Lambda^{d-1}(L) \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow U(L) \otimes \Lambda^1(L) \rightarrow U(L) \rightarrow k,$$

where $\Lambda^\bullet(L)$ denotes the exterior algebra on $L$. Since $U(L)$ is a Hopf algebra, it follows for any (graded) $L$-module $M$ that $P_\bullet \otimes M$ is a $U(L)$-projective resolution of $M$. Then $\textrm{Ext}_{U(L)}^i(M,-)=0$ for $i > d$, so $\textrm{gl dim}(L) \leq d = dim_k(L)$. If $L$ is abelian, then one gets

$$\textrm{Ext}_{U(L)}^i(k,k) \cong \textrm{Hom}_k(\Lambda^i(L),k) \cong \Lambda^i(L^*)$$
and hence $\textrm{gl dim}(L) = d$.

On the other hand, let $L$ be a one-dimensional abelian graded Lie algebra spanned by an element $x$ of $\mathbb{Z}$-degree $1$. Assume that $k$ is not of characteristic $2$. Then

$$U(L) = k[x]/(xx-(-1)^{1 \cdot 1}xx-0) = k[x]/(x^2+x^2) = k[x]/(2x^2) = k[x]/(x^2)$$

i.e., $U(L) = \Lambda(x)$ is an exterior algebra generated by $x$. Then a minimal projective resolution of the trivial $L$-module $k$ is given by the periodic resolution
$$
k \leftarrow \Lambda(x) \stackrel{x}{\leftarrow} \Lambda(x) \stackrel{x}{\leftarrow} \cdots
$$
in which the arrows denote multiplication by $x$. From this it follows that $\textrm{Ext}_{U(L)}^i(k,k) \neq 0$ for all $i \geq 1$, and hence $\textrm{gl dim}(L) = \infty$.

Comment: Are you sure the OP means Lie superalgebras?